# Javascript in HAML in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I've got a question that mightve been asked before but i have trouble finding a proper description. I hope someone can help me out.

In the code below on the line where i set `var price` i want to add the javascript variable `accu_id` to find a record in my DB through rails. How do I do this in embedded rails in javascript?

```
 :javascript
    $('#accu').change(function() {
      var accu_id = $("#accu")[0].selectedOptions[0].value
      var price = "#{currency(Product.find_by(id: accu_id).price2)}"
      $('#price_accu').append(price)
    });
```

Or is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Why are you mixing up pure JS and jQuery?

Comment: The best way would be to use AJAX and do the query inside your controller. You can't add JS variables inside an embedded ruby in this context. I guess this could be a good guidance in how to achieve that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15422887/615410

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options.

1. You can use AJAX request to get data from database
2. You can use mapping concept like following

   var data = @processed_data // json data, which contains processed data in json format. 
   var accu_id = $("#accu")[0].selectedOptions[0].value 
   var price = data.accu_id;

Here the @processed_data contains data like following

```
@processed_data = currency_calculation

def currency_calculation
   Product.all.map { |product| [product.id, currency(product.price2) ] }.as_json 
end
```

Example

Assume products table have two entries then the @processed_data contain values like following

```
{ "1" => "20.00", "2" => "25.50" }
```

The above data directly assigned to js variable **data** and accessed like **data.key**

The first option is best choice and second is possible one.

**Note** : You can't use js variable inside ruby.